# Changes to the my.cnf file on ubuntu does not commit the system variables values?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We have a mariadb instance running on ubuntu below is the version info:

```
| Variable_name           | Value                           |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.26-76.0                     |
| protocol_version        | 10                              |
| slave_type_conversions  |                                 |
| version                 | 10.0.23-MariaDB-1~trusty-log    |
| version_comment         | mariadb.org binary distribution |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                          |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu                |
| version_malloc_library  | bundled jemalloc                |
```

I want to make changes to max_allowed_packet global variable , when is alter the value in the my.cnf file it does not alter the value inspite of restarting the myssqld service.

However, when in set the value using SET GLOBAL MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET = 512; in mysql it does and when i restart the mysqld it resets to the default value.

How do I harden the change, making changes in my.cnf file does not seem to work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Value is to low. The Range is:

```
Range: 1024 to 1073741824
```

see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/server-system-variables/#max_allowed_packet

Answer (score 0):

Was the change in the `[mysqld]` section of `my.cnf`?  The syntax is just

```
max_allowed_packet = 512
```

You don't need to restart mysqld if you both change my.cnf and do `SET GLOBAL MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET = ...` manually.

I have never seen that low a value.  16M is more reasonable unless you have a tiny amount of RAM.

Be careful of making changes to my.cnf, you can cause more harm than benefit.  If you would like, we could review the ideas you have.